# Installing local go package

Tags: go

I want to install a go package locally. Let's pretend I'm not using git and I have no network connection. I just want to write the following demo "library":

mkdir mylib && cd mylib && go mod init locallib/mylib

```
package main

func GetSecretNumber() int {
    return 3
}
```

Now I just want to install this "library" on my machine. So that in a completely separate package I can do:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "locallib/mylib"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("The secret number from the lib is: %d\n", mylib.GetSecretNumber())
}
```

I just want this trivial example to work locally. I don't care about git, github, publishing or versioning. Do the go tool allow me to compile the mylib package and install it locally using any available commands?

Comment: [Module Paths](https://go.dev/ref/mod#module-path) and [Finding a repository for a module path](https://go.dev/ref/mod#vcs-find) may be useful here.

Answer (score 2):

> Now I just want to install this "library" on my machine.

This is a) not necessary and b) not sensible for Go code. Go code is always compiled from source and you do not "install libraries".

> I don't care about git, github, publishing or versioning.

Fine. nobody force you to care about this.

> Do the go tool allow me to compile the mylib package and install it locally using any available commands?

Again no, because that is *unnecessary*

> I just want this trivial example to work locally.

Fine. Either:

- Put both in one module: No more work needed (except using a proper import path for your library. Don't botch that up like you did). Or
- Put them into two modules in which case you:

  - Use a go.work file to link both module into one workspace, or
  - You replace the included module.

Dead simple and trivial.

Please consult the Tutorials on go.dev/doc which explain how to set up moduels and import from them in detail.